# Hochschild homology of a tensor algebra modulo a two-sided ideal

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, hochschild-homology, associative-algebras

Let $V$ is a module over a field $k$, and $A=T(V)$ the tensor algebra generated by $V$. The Hochschild homology $HH_*(A)$ has been determined by Loday and Quillen in their paper "Cyclic homology and the Lie algebra homology of matrices". I was wondering if anything is known about $HH_*(A)$ when $A$ is taken to be $T(V)$ modulo a two-sided ideal $I$, even for something simple such as when $I$ generated by lie brackets $[u,v]$, for some $u,v\in V$?

Comment: All algebras are quotients of tensor algebras, right?

Comment: Look at goodwillie's theorem